# showing messages dynamically in dialog

Tags: jsf, primefaces

i have a project which has transactions. i need to show a message with a dialog if the transaction's status is A or B. what i want to do is to show a message for each status, like: "warning, the status is A" or "warning the status is B". my current code is something like this:

xhtml:

```
    <p:dialog header="Warning" id="I_dialog" widgetVar="transactionDialogWdgt"
        message="This operation is unavailable due to transaction's status">
    </p:dialog>
```

view.java:

```
    if(transaction.getStatus() == 'A' || transaction.getStatus() == 'B'){
        getFacesHelper().executeJS("PF('transactionDialogWdgt').show();");
    }
```

I probably need to send a message from the if block in the view.java class above. But I am not sure how to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You want to update the dialog and get the message from a bean. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339056/understanding-primefaces-process-update-and-jsf-fajax-execute-render-attributes

Answer (score 1):

Might not be exactly what you need but try this:

Put this in some void function that executes after action, say - status change button or different server side function that executes when variable is being changed.

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage("Warning, the status is: " + variableName);
PrimeFaces.current().dialog().showMessageDynamic(message);
```

This should pop up small box in the middle of the screen with the message and option to close it.

If you want to use growl instead (small message in the corner of the screen that doesn't interrupt user) try:

```
FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "INFO", "Warning, the status is: " + variableName);
        addMessage(message);
```

Second one requires you yo put following line somewhere in main xhtml form (at least that's where I put it):

```
<p:growl id="messages" showDetail="true" />
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Nice, but I wouldn't use severity INFO on a warning ;-)

Comment: True haha, just coppied it right from some project that had similar setup from some time ago, FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN is what he might want to try instead